# Is there a way to use firebase secret environment variables in slack/bolt

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

We operate bots by combining Firebase and Slack/bolt.
I currently use `functions.config()`to manage my Slack tokens and secrets, but would like to migrate to using Secret Manager.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#secret-manager

---

```
boltapp.js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { App, ExpressReceiver, subtype } = require("@slack/bolt");
const config = functions.config();
const expressReceiver = new ExpressReceiver({
    signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SECRET,
    endpoints: "/events",
    processBeforeResponse: true,
});

const app = new App({
    receiver: expressReceiver,
    token: process.env.SLACK_TOKEN
});
app.error(error => { console.error(error) });

app.use(async ({ client, payload, context, next }) => {
    console.info('It\'s payload', JSON.stringify(payload))
    if (!context?.retryNum) {
        await next();
    } else {
        console.debug('app.use.context', context);
    }
});

//**bot processing**//

// https://{your domain}.cloudfunctions.net/slack/events
module.exports = functions
    .runWith({ secrets: ["SLACK_TOKEN","SLACK_SECRET"] })
    .https.onRequest(expressReceiver.app);
```

But when I rewrote it for migration, I got the following error.
Is there a way to rewrite the code while avoiding this error?

> Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Apps used in a single workspace can be initialized with a token. Apps used in many workspaces should be initialized with oauth installer options or authorize.

> Since you have not provided a token or authorize, you might be missing one or more required oauth installer options. See https://slack.dev/bolt-js/concepts#authenticating-oauth for these required fields.

Answer (score 0):

Secrets can only be read at the time the function is being called. So a pattern like this can be used

```js
const makeApp = () => {
    const app = new App({
        receiver: expressReceiver,
        token: process.env.SLACK_TOKEN
    });
    // etc
    return expressReceiver.app
}

export const slack = functions
  .runWith({secrets})
  .https
  .onRequest((req,res) => makeApp()(req, res));
```